# Unable to start new activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

Every time I try to start new activity, an error occurs (Java null pointer exception) and the app fc's: I tried every single way and it just doesn't work! Here's an example for the code : MainAct is the first activity and NewAct is the activity to launch...
1- manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.NewAct"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_newact" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NewAct" />

        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2-MainAct:

```
 Button bt;
        bt = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bt);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i= new Intent ("com.example.app.NewAct");
                                     startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

I also tried other forms of intent such as

```
Intent i= new Intent ("android.intent.action.NewAct");

Intent i= new Intent (this, NewAct.class);

Intent i= new Intent (view.getContext(), StudentInfoActivity.class);
```

Comment: Could you post your `MainAct` and `NewAct` classes please? :)

Comment: Could you add some LogCat output relating to the crash to see if it occurs in MainAct or while starting up NewAct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get the context from the "`view`" get the context from the `Activity`. Wherever you need a context use `getApplicationContext()`, `getActivity()`, or `this`. But if you are inside of an `Anonymous Inner Class`, such as a `View.OnClickListener()` (as you are in the code you posted) you cannot use `this` because `this` will be referring to the `Anonymous Inner Class` that you are in.

A common practice would be storing the `Context` away in a `private member variable`, do this inside of `onCreate()`...

Ex.

```
....
private Context mContext;
...
@Override
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  mContext = this;

}
```

^By doing this you have a context variable to use freely throughout your activity without having to worry.

Try something like this to start your new `Activity`, after you have your `Context` variable:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext,
                NewAct.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

^You can use this code from within your `OnClickListener()`.

Comment: Get rid of the `intent filter`, I'm not sure why that's even there. This is how you start an `Activity` by the books..

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainAct.this, NewAct.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Do you need the intent filter for newact activity? Maybe try without it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your Intent.please check your onCreate() of the second Activity[NewAct.java].

Comment: what are the things that should be in the NewAct onCreate?? I'm new to programming and I have no experience with such things